# Is there such a thing as a "local" scoped bean in CDI?

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi

By "local" I mean that the bean is created and destroyed during a method call. That's basically the same as just calling a constructor, the advantage would be the ability to use @Inject in that bean's fields.

**Why do I want to do that**
I'm refactoring legacy code that uses CDI. I'd like to [extract very long methods into classes](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-method-with-method-object). Local variables from the method will be replaced by fields in the class, so the bean will have a state that belongs only to that short-lived scope (the duration of a method call). The bean will also depend on services and other wider-scoped beans that I'd rather inject than pass on a long argument list to the constructor.

Comment: If you refactor the classes, you could just make them a "stateless" applicationscoped beans, so that you dont need to think about such narrower scopes

Answer (score 0):

CDI does not support method injection (apart from setters and constructors). So this cannot be done because @Dependent scope is dependent on the containing bean not the caller method.

Also in your case even if this worked it would produce an infinite loop as you need to pass the container to the child then the child to the container and so on.

The solution would be to inject a factory instead.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the standard CDI scopes, `@RequestScoped` is probably the best fit for your short-lived beans, even if their lifetime is longer than just a single method call.

Stateless `@ApplicationScoped` beans (e.g. services) can work with any number of `@RequestScoped` beans (e.g. commands) in parallel.

If that doesn't suit you, you can always define a custom scope using a CDI extension.